# Python package structure

Tags: python, package

I have a Python package with several subpackages.

```
myproject/
  __init__.py
  models/
    __init__.py
    ...
  controllers/
    __init__.py
    ..
  scripts/
    __init__.py
    myscript.py
```

Within myproject.scripts.myscript, how can I access myproject.models?  I've tried

```
from myproject import models # No module named myproject
import models # No module named models
from .. import models # Attempted relative import in non-package
```

I've had to solve this before, but I can never remember how it's supposed to be done.  It's just not intuitive to me.

Comment: How are you running `myscript.py`?  Could you show us your command line?  That will make a difference to the answer.

Comment: Try `import myproject.models`

Comment: Okay, I found a solution: `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))` before import.  I hope there is a better solution though.

Comment: It's probably got to do with your pythonpath. Where are you trying to import this package from? If it's not in the same location as the package you have to add it to the pythonpath.

Comment: Brandon Craig Rhodes: I am in the myproject/ directory, and I am running `python scripts/myscript.py`.

Comment: @adeel: did you try `import myproject.models`?

Comment: John: Yes, that works only if I set PYTHONPATH as Jean-Paul Calderone mentioned in his answer.

Comment: Ok then.  I guess Jean-Paul gets an upvote from me.  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is the correct version:

```
from myproject import models
```

If it fails with `ImportError: No module named foo` it is because you haven't set `PYTHONPATH` to include the directory which contains `myproject/`.

I'm afraid other people will suggest tricks to let you avoid setting `PYTHONPATH`.  I urge you to disregard them.  This is why `PYTHONPATH` exists: to tell Python where to look for code to load.  It is robust, reasonably well documented, and portable to many environments.  Tricks people play to avoid having to set it are none of these things.

The explicit relative import ***will*** work even without `PYTHONPATH` being set, since it can just walk up the directory hierarchy until it finds the right place, it doesn't need to find the top and then walk down.  However, it doesn't work in a script you pass as a command line argument to `python` (or equivalently, invoke directly with a `#!/usr/bin/python` line).  This is because in both these cases, it becomes the `__main__` module of the process.  There's nowhere to walk up to from `__main__` - it's already at the top!  If you invoke the code in your script by *importing* that module, then it will be fine.  That is, compare:

```
python myproject/scripts/myscript.py
```

to

```
python -c 'import myproject.scripts.myscript'
```

You can take advantage of this by not executing your script module directly, but creating a `bin/myscript` that does the import and perhaps calls a main function:

```
import myprojects.scripts.myscript
myprojects.scripts.myscript.main()
```

Compare to how Twisted's command line scripts are defined: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/bin/twistd

Comment: Thanks.  Can you explain why `from .. import models` doesn't work?  I thought relative imports would allow you to do this without setting PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Thanks, Jean-Paul!  I like that approach.

Answer (score 2):

Your project is not in your path.

Option A

- Install your package so that python can find it via its absolute name from anywhere (using `from myproject import models` )

Option B

- Trickery to add the relative parent to your path
- `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('..'))`

The former option is recommended.