# How to import using a top level path in Python?

Tags: python, package

I'm developing a python framework and want to do imports based on the top-level package (the project name). Users will use the framework by copying the entire framework and writing their own modules within.

My current structure looks like this:

```
myapp/
  config.py
  docs/
  framework/
    main.py
    utils.py
  file.py
  lib/
    some_module.py
  unit_tests/
    test_utils.py
```

I want to be able to use the following import in python files in lib and unit_tests in the following way:

```
from myapp.framework import utils
```

Is there a simple way to do this? I've tried doing sys.path.append() hacks but they don't really work. If there is a truly pythonic way to achieve this, I don't mind going extra lengths to get it working.

EDIT: Well I tried the sys.path.append() again and it actually works but it really is an in-elegant solution and I'd really like to hear if there's another way.

Comment: Why doesn't `sys.path.append()` work?

Comment: @ire_and_curses - I'm not sure why sys.path.append() wasn't working as I just wasn't able to achieve the desired import I wanted. However, from my research it seems like adding to the path is not recommended.

Comment: Very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747598/python-package-structure

Answer (score 2):

For short: You can't have two modules with the same name one inside the other. You have the `myapp` folder and the `myapp.py` file

That's because of the order of importing modules.

1. Inside the current directory
2. The current package
3. Global package folder

So, if you're trying to `import myapp.lib.some_module` in config.py the interpreter will first see that you have myapp.py in the same folder and literaly try to import `lib.some_module` from that file, which doesn't exist.

Would be something as trying to import `myapp.myapp.lib.some_module` from outside that module.

So, the best thing for you to do is to rename the `myapp.py` file

Comment: Oops sorry, the myapp.py file was supposed to be a placeholder file to show that there's other files. It's not actually present in the framework. I'll edit it out of the question.