# How to import modules from different folders in Python?

Tags: python

How to import modules from different folders? I have the following

```
cgi-bin
       | py
          |
           __init.py__
           http
             |
              __init.py__
              HttpFormParser.py
           xml
             |
              __init.py__
              XmlDocumentCreator.py
```

I want to import XmlDocumentCreator in HttpFormParser.py. How to do that ?

I'm doing

```
import py.xml.XmlDocumentCreator
```

in HttpFormParser.py and its throwing the following error.

```
/HttpFormParser.py", line 5, in <module> 
    import py.xml.XmlDocumentCreator
ImportError: No module named py.xml.XmlDocumentCreator
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python package structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747598/python-package-structure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just work out the directory you're executing from, as told by `sys.argv[0]`. In this case, you want to get the `cgi-bin` directory since it contains `py`:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 
    os.pardir, os.pardir)))
import py.xml.XmlDocumentCreator
```

P.S. if you're using WSGI, you don't need your Python code in a `cgi-bin` directory, where it could be downloaded if your `.htaccess` (or equivalent) is set wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
from ..xml import XmlDocumentCreator
```

?

Generally I encourage you to read sections **The Module Search Path** and **Intra-package References** @ http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html