# Import program in other folders with Python

Tags: python

I want to import a Python program from 2 different folders:

- `Prog1` from the path `/home/francis/docs/folder1/`
- `Prog2` from the path `/home/francis/docs/folder2/`

How do I import these two Programs in my main program situated in `/home/francis/docs/folder3/`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import modules from different folders in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131899/how-to-import-modules-from-different-folders-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to the top of your Prog3:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/francis/docs/folder1/')
sys.path.append('/home/francis/docs/folder2/')
import Prog1
import Prog2
```

Answer (score 1):

See also another related question:
[How to import modules from different folders in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131899/how-to-import-modules-from-different-folders-in-python)

And http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

Add the other two folders to `PYTHONPATH`, then simply import them as usual with `import folder1`. From the documentation at http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter searches for a file named spam.py in the directory containing the input script and then in the list of directories specified by the environment variable PYTHONPATH. This has the same syntax as the shell variable PATH, that is, a list of directory names. When PYTHONPATH is not set, or when the file is not found there, the search continues in an installation-dependent default path; on Unix, this is usually .:/usr/local/lib/python.

Also see the documentation for PYTHONPATH itself: http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add

```
"/home/francis/docs/"
```

to your pythonpath, and then :

```
from folder1 import prog1
```

or

```
import folder1.prog1 as p1
```

(you will have to adjust the     **init**    files in folder1 and folder2 with the contents)