# How to structure python project with dot "." or underscore "-" in project/package name?

Tags: python, package, pep

[PEP 423](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0423) states that project names and package names should be the same and later gives an [example where the project/package name contains a dot](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0423/#use-a-single-name):

> Yes:
> Package name: "kheops.pyramid", i.e. `import kheops.pyramid`
> Project name: "kheops.pyramid", i.e. `pip install kheops.pyramid`

What would the directory structure be for `kheops.pyramid` and how would `setup.py` be written (specifically the `name` and `packages` values) for that directory structure?

I've also seen that [PEP 503](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0503/#normalized-names) states that names should be normalized by replacing `_`, `-`, and `.` with `-`. Does this mean that `kheops-pyramid` should be used rather than `kheops.pyramid`? If so, wouldn't I need a package whose directory name is `kheops-pyramid` and wouldn't the `-` cause issues (eg. syntax error) when trying to `import kheops-pyramid`?

**EDIT**:
I tried to make a project/package `kheops.pyramid` to adhere to [PEP 423](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0423/#top-level-namespace-relates-to-code-ownership) but I cannot figure out what directory structure and `setup.py` combination will allow me to `import kheops.pyramid`  after `pip install kheops.pyramid` without an error like `ImportError: No module named kheops.pyramid`.

Comment: Have you looked at *"namespace packages"*? See e.g. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/

Comment: @jonrsharpe I had not seen PEP 420 before. It definitely seems relevant but not sure I understand how to address my problem still.

Comment: What *is* your problem? Are you trying to make a package with a `.` in the name and failing?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes. i am trying to make a project/package like `username.package` to adhere to PEP 423 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0423/#top-level-namespace-relates-to-code-ownership but I cannot figure out what directory structure and `setup.py` combination will allow me to `import username.package`  after `pip install username.package` without an error like `ImportError: No module named username.package`. Will edit the question to make this more apparent.

Comment: You need `kheops` to exist first in order for `kheops.pyramid` to be possible.

Comment: @tripleee not sure what type of thing `kheops` is in your comment: project, package, directory?

Comment: A package, I guess. Tangentially, see also stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PEP 423 is deferred](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0423/#pep-deferral), so I ended doing to equivalent of `pyramid` rather than `kheops.pyramid` via standard python packaging. [Here is the package](https://github.com/pcattori/namespaces) I came up with as an example.

Answer (score 0):

`from username import package` should work.

Are you sure about your `PYTHONPATH` ?

You might want to try executing the system commands after `PYTHONPATH=.` ? This is because you perhaps haven't set `PYTHONPATH` to include the directory which contains `username/`

You might also want to check [Python Package Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747598/python-package-structure?rq=1).